# Check input is between range of numbers -in C#

Tags: c#, console

In console app I am trying to check if input value for years is between 1-10.

Currently I am also checking if input is a valid int using the following method.

```
int numberOfYears;

Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of years:");
string numberOfYearsInput = Console.ReadLine();

while (!Int32.TryParse(numberOfYearsInput, out numberOfYears))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid ammount, try again.");

    numberOfYearsInput = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I have tried changing this to:

```
while (!Int32.TryParse(numberOfYearsInput, out numberOfYears))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid ammount, try again.");

    numberOfYearsInput = Console.ReadLine();

    if (numberOfYears < 1 || numberOfYears > 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not a valid ammount, try again.");

        numberOfYearsInput = Console.ReadLine();   
    }
}
```

However, this is allowing incorrect input value. How can I combine this to make it work?

**EDIT**

Have changed to below and still allowing 11, 12 etc as valid input

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of years:");
string numberOfYearsInput = Console.ReadLine();

while (!Int32.TryParse(numberOfYearsInput, out numberOfYears))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid ammount, try again.");

    numberOfYearsInput = Console.ReadLine();

    if (numberOfYears >= 1 && numberOfYears <= 10)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Not a valid ammount, try again.");

         numberOfYearsInput = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is 11 is a valid integer so passes the while loop

Comment: ` if (numberOfYears >1 || numberOfYears < 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not a valid ammount, try again.");

        numberOfYearsInput = Console.ReadLine();

    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that kind of tasks should be made by oop standarts, for example

```
    public static bool BetweenRanges(int a,int b,int number)
    {
        return (a <= number && number <= b);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of years:");
        int numberOfYearsInput = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

        while (!BetweenRanges(1,10, numberOfYearsInput))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not a valid ammount, try again.");
            numberOfYearsInput = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }
```

in that case you can use `BetweenRange` in more places and with any kinds of numbers. the code are cleaner and better for understanding maybe not critical in that case but its the best practices. (will be mutch easy to understand when your code will grow)

in case of text input you can check it and tell the user that text is not allowed:

```
    public static bool BetweenRanges(int a, int b, int number)
    {
        return (a <= number && number <= b);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool notValid = true;

        while (notValid)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of years:");
                int numberOfYearsInput = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

                while (!BetweenRanges(1, 10, numberOfYearsInput))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid ammount, try again.");
                    numberOfYearsInput = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
                }

                notValid = false;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Text is not valid ammount, try again.\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Leon, but unfortunately this will break if user enters text etc. which is also my requirement.

Comment: try the secound option (tell the user that text is not allowed)

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement you use the '||', but that is a boolean OR, you need to use an 'AND' statement. Additionally, your smaller/larger operators is inverted, thus giving you the statement:

if numberOfYears is Smaller than 1 OR numberOfYears is larger than 10

if you want to check if the number is between 1 and 10, the line should be this:

```
if (numberOfYears >= 1 && numberOfYears <= 10)
```

the `'&&'` is the boolean `'AND'` operator
the `'>='` and `'<='` is larger/smaller than or equal to, respecivly.

thus it checks if numberOfYears is larger or equal to 1 AND smaller or equal to 10.

Comment: Thanks but it still allows 11 as a valid input

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's allowing incorrect input is because you are using the OR operand (||).

This basically tells the compiler that the year needs to be *higher* than 1 **OR** *lower* than 10.

So if you add a number, say 100, that actually is evaluated to true, since it holds true in the left-hand side of the if-statements condition. (Higher than 1).

So change it to:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int numberOfYears = GetYears();

    Console.WriteLine("Good work, years = " + numberOfYears);
}

public static int GetYears()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of years:");

    string inputYears = Console.ReadLine();
    int years;

    while(!(Int32.TryParse(inputYears, out years)) 
          || (years < 1  || years > 10))               
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not a valid ammount, higher than 1, lower than 10!"); 
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a new number");
        inputYears = Console.ReadLine(); 
    } 

    return years;
}
```

Here is a fiddle holding the a solution to the problem asked for in the comments: [**Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g18Wym)

Comment: if will be always false

Comment: What are you talking about? 
How could this always be false? I just tested it in VS. As long as the variable is higher than 1 and lower than 10 (as the requirements were), it will be true, else false. Check out this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5QWeE9).

Comment: lets suppose your number is 5 then if(false&&false)

Comment: Just realized I set the equal signs wrong. You are correct. Edited.

Comment: Thanks but it still allows 11 as a valid input

Comment: Yes, it does, simply because 11 is a valid tryparse. I'll edit with a more robust solution.

Comment: @TomL tell me if you need any clarification on the solution. It might even be better to abstract the comparison in a separate method so that you can set up some unit tests to it.

Comment: Hi, sorry but it is returning the first number input and not the correct number input?

Comment: That might happen on the fiddle, since I used some recursion. The sample should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        int numberOfYears;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of years:");
        string numberOfYearsInput = Console.ReadLine();
        bool result = false;

        while (!result)
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(numberOfYearsInput, out numberOfYears))
            {
                if (numberOfYears < 1 || numberOfYears > 10)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid ammount, try again.");

                    numberOfYearsInput = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    result = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("Correct Number");
                    Console.ReadKey(true);
                    //Do your code here
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number, try again.");
                numberOfYearsInput = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but I thought using `goto` is not best practice.

Comment: I also think you should avoid `goto`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the question is from a beginner, now I edited my code

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in this line of code `while (!Int32.TryParse(numberOfYearsInput, out numberOfYears))`, as it passes all valid numbers and enters the loop only if the input is not a valid number.

Try to use this piece of code and let me know if it works fine for you

```
       int numberOfYears;

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not a valid ammount, try again.");
            if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfYears))
                continue;

            if (numberOfYears >= 1 && numberOfYears <= 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Valid value");
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following :

```
    public static bool IsWithin(this int number, int from, int to)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(from, to).Contains(number);
    }
```

and use the above extension method as following :

```
if(age.IsWithin(25, 30))
{
 // do something
}
```